# How can I understand the difference between ethernet controller over PCie and USB

Tags: usb, driver, ethernet

I need to write an ethernet driver for ASIX AX-88179-(USB 3.0 ethernet controller) for a proprietary OS. Can please someone guide me how can I understand the difference between ethernet controller over PCie and USB?. Any good books or urls which i can refer?. Please help !!

I am a beginner. I tried searching over internet about the functional difference of ethernet controller communicates over PCie and USB bus. I am looking for starting pointers

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's your OS, the ethernet driver depends on the OS extremely.

linux pcie ethernet driver(rtl8169) look at:https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.9.300/source/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek/r8169.c
linux USB  ethernet driver look at(**ASIX AX-88179**): https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.9.300/source/drivers/net/usb/ax88179_178a.c

1. protocol stack initialize（OS）
   OS initialize protocol stack, provide  API functions for driver,in linux is:
   netif_receive_skb: driver sends a packet to protocol stack
   netdev_alloc_skb: driver malloc packet memory
2. controller initialize(OS )
   OS initialize CPU's USB/PCIe controller, create USB/PCIe device
   OS provides APIs to send/receive packages by USB/PCIe controller
3. ethernet driver
   in Linux ethernet driver implements struct net_device_ops.
   register packet receive function to protocol stack
   register pcie/usb irq function to OS